# How to add condition on the left table to include “zero” / “0” results in COUNT aggregate?

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I have an SQL-select:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  COUNT(a.id)
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Account a
ON a.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

and it works fine. But if I add a condition on left table this query will return no rows instead of zero count:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  COUNT(a.id)
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Account a
ON a.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1 AND a.state = '0'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

How can add the condition on the left table that returns 0 count in case there are no results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *second* table need to be in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(a.id)
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
     Account a
     ON a.person_id = p.id AND a.state = '0'
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

The rule is pretty simple to follow.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, even when there is no match in the second table.  The values in the second table become `NULL`.  The `NULL` value will fail the condition `a.state = '0'`.